# How to find a dropdown value using search?

Tags: sharepoint-online

In my SharePoint Online enviroment:
I have a Dropdown Site column called Project Status.

I have mapped the Site column to a RefinableString11

I made sure to have values in the column.

Now I have waited a week for the full crawl to happen.

My value didnt get picked up by search.

So my question is 2 part.

1. Does SharePoint Online understand dropdown values?
2. If not how can I make SharePoint give me the values from my column so I can use those values to build my quarry string?

Initial Query:

```
path:"https://mySharePoint site" contentclass:"STS_Web"  Title<>"External Work Areas"
```

It works and returns all values.

Now I added the project status so I could differentiate between open and closed projects so i wanted to do this:

```
path:"https://mySharePoint site" contentclass:"STS_Web"  Title<>"External Work Areas" AND  RefinableString11=Open
```

Comment: You don't need to map site columns. A managed property is automatically created for them.

Comment: @Akhoy great! that still doesnt answer if drop downs can be used and what else i could do.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj613136.aspx, the managed property for choice columns is `SiteColumnNameOWSCHCS`.

So, try using `ProjectStatusOWSCHCS` as the managed property.

If it has "multiple values allowed," use `ProjectStatusOWSCHCM`.

Comment: @Cherubel did this work? Just curious :)